# Count string spaces in Java

Tags: java, string

Question is simple.

"abcd".length() == 4

also, it takes 4 spaces when I print it.

so, how about this?

"漢語".length() == 2

but it takes 4 spaces...

Is there any library or method to calculate spaces every language?
(I don't want some graphical methods...)

---

#### Update

Example. The word "안녕abc" takes 7 spaces by System.out.println()

```
-------
안녕abc
String.length() : 5
```

Comment: Why do you say it takes 4 spaces? The pinyin is HanYu, which is 5 characters, There are a total of 2 Chinese characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the display width of a string as counted in spaces.

Depends on the font. And sometimes for Asiatic script an other font or font size is taken. Also spaces can be very narrow in some fonts. `n`-width is a more used measure for comparison.

```
public static double spaceWidth(Font font, String text) {
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(font.getTransform(), true, true);
    Rectangle2D textRect = font.getStringBounds(text, frc);
    Rectangle2D spaceRect = font.getStringBounds(" ", frc);
    return textRect.getWidth() / spaceRect.getWidth();
}  

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Font font = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 10);
    System.out.println("Font: " + font.getFamily());

    String s = "안녕abc";
    //         "      " (6 spaces)
    System.out.printf("'%s' -> %f%n", s, spaceWidth(font, s));
}
```

> 6.332791

A Math.round would the "round" things up. As you see, this will not give exact 6 spaces, even though the font is "monospaced".

For tabular output better use HTML with a TABLE or such.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean bytes by spaces.

```
System.out.println( "漢語".getBytes().length ); // -> 6
```

Where String.length() returns length of the sequence of characters (2).

The measureable space required for printing characters depends on the font used.

Using a [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object you could calculate this using the font metrics:

```
g.setFont(new Font("SomeSuitableFont", Font.BOLD, 24));
int width = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth("漢語");
```

Comment: documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html